# MongoDB: truth behind find({...}).limit(#)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

In MongoDB, does `.find({...}).limit(#)` really limit the number of queries?

I mean, when you do `db.collection.find(condition)`, doesn't it already waste computational power to query all the results that match the given condition? If so, then does adding `.limit()` after it just strip off the unneeded elements from the query results?

Thanks a lot for clarifying this up!

Answer (score 5):

`db.collection.find` returns a [*`cursor`*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor), not an array of results or similar. From the documentation:

> When the `find()` method “returns documents,” the method is actually returning a `cursor` to the documents.

The documents are actually located when you *iterate* the cursor. So calling `.limit` tells the cursor when to say it's done iterating.

More about cursors here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/#read-operations-cursors

Comment: old question, but still need some clarifications !
In NodeJS what is a "cursor" ? a promise ? it should be since it can be awaited :

Comment: `let cursor = User.find().limit(5); let array = await cursor;`. But `cursor instanceof Promise` returns false !

Comment: OK i get it : ["Thenable objects" can be awaited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). So, Mongo cursor is not a promise, but an object which provides a then() method. Crystal clear.

Comment: @JosephMerdrignac- You can `await` any value; it doesn't do anything (other than wait for one async "tick") if that value isn't a *thenable*. I don't use MongoDB, but I don't see anything in the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Cursor.html) suggesting that cursors are thenables. They have some *methods* that return promises, but [cursors themselves](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/lib_cursor.js.html) don't seem to have a `then` method (with the `node-mongodb-native` driver, anyway).

Comment: You're right in JS everything can be awaited, and i'm using mongoose, the NodeJS Driver, where queries are object with a then() method. I even found some official documentation : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises I was ignoring the concept of "thenable" objects (and therefore was convinced that if any value could be awaited, only the value of promises instances will change through the process).

Answer (score 4):

limit() is not used for post filtering of data. You can figure out this using explain(). For example, I have fired 2  queries 1)db.album.find().explain() 2) db.album.find().limit(5).explain(); here is resultant:

```
        > db.album.find().explain()
       {
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 1000,
        "nscannedObjects" : 1000,
        "nscanned" : 1000,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1000,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 1000,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 54,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 12,
        "server" : "delbsinha25125:27017",
       "filterSet" : false
      }

      > db.album.find().limit(5).explain()
        {
         "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
         "isMultiKey" : false,
         "n" : 5,
         "nscannedObjects" : 5,
         "nscanned" : 5,
         "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 5,
         "nscannedAllPlans" : 5,
         "scanAndOrder" : false,
         "indexOnly" : false,
         "nYields" : 0,
         "nChunkSkips" : 0,
         "millis" : 0,
          "server" : "delbsinha25125:27017",
         "filterSet" : false
      }
```

As you can see from the above execution plan, the one with limit has scanned only 5 objects.

>

Comment: Of course this is not a good example since the reason why nscanned is 5 is because it literally only need to read 5, it is a special case, if you had a more complex query you will find that nscanned can change beyond limit

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to answer this question about 5 days ago but then found some interesting things that I had to actually investigate.

Limit is applied after sort and find, however, not before iteration of those results within the `mongod` (MongoDB) server itself, as such this means that if done right you can save a lot of computational power using limit. @Bipul's answer is a perfect eample of this but it doesn't go as far as to show the true limitations of what MongoDB can achieve here.

It should be noted that if you are using the latest version of MongoDB there is actually a bug with limit which causes etra entries to be scanned: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14712 which was one of the things I actually found while attempting to answer this question.

It should be noted that the bug mentioned above only effects inde usage with limit.

Now considering @Bipuls answer without inde usage there is actually two sides to this story, one being what he has shown but the other also being if you add a sort:

```
> db.rooms.find().sort({d:1}).limit(2).explain()
{
        "clauses" : [
                {
                        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "n" : 2,
                        "nscannedObjects" : 5,
                        "nscanned" : 5,
                        "scanAndOrder" : true,
                        "indexOnly" : false,
                        "nChunkSkips" : 0
                },
                {
                        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "n" : 0,
                        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                        "nscanned" : 0,
                        "scanAndOrder" : true,
                        "indexOnly" : false,
                        "nChunkSkips" : 0
                }
        ],
        "cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
        "n" : 2,
        "nscannedObjects" : 5,
        "nscanned" : 5,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 5,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 5,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "server" : "ubuntu:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```

The size of the collection being 5, you can see the limit has been applied after sort as such it shows that the collection had to be fully scanned and since this query has no inde it would have been a full inde scan and your computational saving will be nothing more than "by the looks of it".

Now if you add an inde this is different, it can actually use the order of the inde to stop a full scan and load only as far as your limit goes, however, due to the bug above it will always scan one more than needed, but that is an inde scan, not an actual document being loaded (depending on whether your queries find() is covered or not).

So to sum up, limit, when used correctly, can stop MongoDB from having to load ecessive documents, not only saving your working set but also your IO bandwidth. If you can use limit correctly with the inde etc then I would definitely recommend it.